# How can I change info box color text in AdminLTE scss file

Tags: sass, adminlte

I can't find how can I change info box color text in AdminLTE scss file.

My steps:

1. Download repo https://github.com/ColorlibHQ/AdminLTE
2. Open folder, run npm install command, run npm dev command
3. Change color blue, red, green on darker shades

I Want change color text, icon etc. in info box on white in scss - how?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.